# How To Pass Selenium Server Log Parameter Via Protractor

Tags: javascript, node.js, selenium, protractor

I'm hoping somebody can help with the following issue I'm having. I'm trying to start selenium server via protractor with some command line parameters

(I use this link for reference https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/lib/config.ts)

I'm able to set a few command line parameters

```
localSeleniumStandaloneOpts:
{

     args: [

               '-Dwebdriver.chrome.driver=./node_modules/protractor/node_modules/webdriver-manager/selenium/chromedriver_2.26.exe',

               '-Dwebdriver.chrome.logfile=./Results/browser_logs_chrome.log',

               '-Dwebdriver.gecko.driver=./node_modules/protractor/node_modules/webdriver-manager/selenium/geckodriver-v0.11.1.exe',

               '-Dwebdriver.gecko.logfile=./Results/browser_logs_firefox.log',

               '-Dwebdriver.ie.driver=./node_modules/protractor/node_modules/webdriver-manager/selenium/IEDriverServer_Win32_2.53.1.exe',

               '-Dwebdriver.ie.driver.loglevel=INFO',

               '-log=./Results/selenium_server_logs.log'

           ];

}
```

but I'm never able to get logs for the selenium server? Can somebody guide me on what parameter I should be passing so that I get logs from the local selenium server?

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass [jvmArgs](https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/lib/config.ts#L66) instead of regular [args](https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/lib/config.ts#L59). So when you run the standalone server: `java -jar {jvmArgs} /path/to/standalone-server.jar {args}`

Update:

The args values are separate. The flag and values are separate (updated answer below):

```
localSeleniumStandaloneOpts:
{

     args:    [ '-log=', './Results/selenium_server_logs.log' ],
     jvmArgs: [
                '-Dwebdriver.chrome.driver=./node_modules/protractor/node_modules/webdriver-manager/selenium/chromedriver_2.26.exe',
                '-Dwebdriver.chrome.logfile=./Results/browser_logs_chrome.log',
                '-Dwebdriver.gecko.driver=./node_modules/protractor/node_modules/webdriver-manager/selenium/geckodriver-v0.11.1.exe',
                '-Dwebdriver.gecko.logfile=./Results/browser_logs_firefox.log',
                '-Dwebdriver.ie.driver=./node_modules/protractor/node_modules/webdriver-manager/selenium/IEDriverServer_Win32_2.53.1.exe',
                '-Dwebdriver.ie.driver.loglevel=INFO'
     ]
}
```

This was fixed in November 2016 on [this commit](https://github.com/angular/protractor/commit/f3938f9fcd1b91272f2f11d4d39e458576fb75b0). Protractor 4.0.11+ supports this feature.

Update:

How this was tested. Added a `console.log` to the selenium-webdriver [`remote/index.js`](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/master/javascript/node/selenium-webdriver/remote/index.js#L492). To log the `jvmArgs.concat('-jar', jar, '-port', port).concat(args)`. The values printed when running Protractor:

```
[11:52:49] I/local - Starting selenium standalone server...
[11:52:49] I/launcher - Running 1 instances of WebDriver
[ '-Dwebdriver.chrome.driver=../node_modules/webdriver-manager/selenium/chromedriver_2.26',
  '-Dwebdriver.chrome.logfile=./browser_logs_chrome.log',
  '-Dwebdriver.gecko.driver=../node_modules/webdriver-manager/selenium/geckodriver-v0.11.1',
  '-Dwebdriver.gecko.logfile=./browser_logs_firefox.log',
  '-Dwebdriver.chrome.driver=/usr/local/google/home/cnishina/src/protractor/node_modules/webdriver-manager/selenium/chromedriver_2.26',
  '-jar',
  '/usr/local/google/home/cnishina/src/protractor/node_modules/webdriver-manager/selenium/selenium-server-standalone-2.53.1.jar',
  '-port',
  58308,
  '-log',
  'selenium_server_logs.log',
  '-debug' ]
[11:52:50] I/local - Selenium standalone server started at http://100.66.105.17:58308/wd/hub
Started
```

Also ran this against the Protractor repo example `./bin/protractor example/conf.js` to test. This is the conf used:

```
exports.config = {
  seleniumServerJar: '../node_modules/webdriver-manager/selenium/selenium-server-standalone-2.53.1.jar',
  localSeleniumStandaloneOpts: {
    args: [ '-log','selenium_server_logs.log', '-debug' ],
    jvmArgs: [
      '-Dwebdriver.chrome.driver=../node_modules/webdriver-manager/selenium/chromedriver_2.26',
      '-Dwebdriver.chrome.logfile=./browser_logs_chrome.log',
      '-Dwebdriver.gecko.driver=../node_modules/webdriver-manager/selenium/geckodriver-v0.11.1',
      '-Dwebdriver.gecko.logfile=./browser_logs_firefox.log'
    ]
  },
  specs: ['example_spec.js'],
}
```

This only tested the Chrome browser and created the browser_logs_firefox.log and selenium_server_logs.log file.

Comment: Hi there thanks for responding....I have tried that construct that you mentioned above but unfortunately that doesn't work for me. I'm also using protractor edition 4.0.14. Are we sure this works? The jvmArgs works for me but not the args part.

Comment: I also upgraded to 5.0.0 and it doesn't seem to work for that version too?

Comment: Updating my answer. Got this to work but the args are wrong.

Comment: Thanks for the updated answer. Everything in your updated answer worked for me bar the creation of the Firefox browser logs. I'm using version 50.1.0 of firefox so do I need to upgrade that? In addition, i'm using geckodriver edition v0.12.0. Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Please see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41615695/protractor-starts-firefox-but-doesnt-run-any-tests. You'll need FF 47 for now. Check the Protractor CHANGELOG for more information / supported versions.

Comment: Hey...I'm using firefox 57 and I need a way to turn on geckodriver logs someway via protractor to diagnose an issue. Surely there is a way to do this? This construct above still doesn't work for me